# What is the precedence of Guardian Angel compared to other revive effects?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, there are a number of effects which revive a champion upon death.  The item [Guardian Angel](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Angel) is the most well-known and widely used of these.  I was wondering, however, whether its effect would come before or after other revive effects?

I have two examples.

First, Zilean's ultimate [Chrono Shift](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zilean_the_Chronokeeper/Ability_Details) will provide a champion with a Guardian Angel -like buff for a limited time.  If a champion has this buff *in addition to* a Guardian Angel, which effect will happen first?

Second, Anivia's passive [Rebirth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia_the_Cryophoenix/Ability_Details) allows her to come back to life if her egg is not destroyed after she is killed.  If she has a Guardian Angel, will her passive be triggered before or after it? How does this compare to [Zac's Cell Division](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zac/Ability_Details) and [Aatrox's Blood Well](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aatrox/Ability_Details)?

It seems like in one case it is more beneficial to have Guardian Angel's precedence be greater, and in the other it is more beneficial to have it be less.  In the first scenario, if the Guardian Angel was triggered first, then Zilean would have a good chance of simply wasting his ultimate.  On the other hand, if it is triggered *after* these revival effects, then Anivia could not get the full benefit of her passive.

Is there a set order of precedence, or does each revival effect have their own unique "priority level" that is explicitly detailed for each ability?

Comment: Except that that question and answer doesn't even mention Guardian Angel, which is the focus of my question.

Comment: Edited the question and added links of items/abilities, click any to have your question answered :) the lolwiki has this covered pretty well, anything not mentioned in the links will be covered in the question i linked above

Comment: And what if you are already an egg (as anivia) and suddenly your GA get's off cooldown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the links provided in the question answer it fully, just so we have an accurate answer on the site.

1. [Zilean's Chrono Shift](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zilean_the_Chronokeeper/Ability_Details#Chrono_shift) ability. Caveats being:

   - Chrono Shift will not activate if the holder is killed by the Nexus Obelisk.
   - Chrono Shift will always take precedence over other revival abilities, like  Guardian Angel and  Rebirth.
2. [Guardian Angel](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Angel) item. Caveats being:

   - The passive does not activate when killed by the Nexus Obelisk.
   - Its passive will always activate before  Rebirth, but after the  Chrono Shift buff if the owner has it.
3. 3a [Aniva's Rebirth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia_the_Cryophoenix/Ability_Details) ability. Caveats being:

   - If Anivia is affected by  Chrono Shift,  Omen of Death and/or  Guardian Angel,  Chrono Shift will activate first,  Guardian Angel second, and Rebirth will be third.  Omen of Death will have last priority, granting Anivia the potential to survive up to four "deaths".
4. 3b [Zac's Cell Division](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zac/Ability_Details) passive.

   - Each bloblet is 12% of Zac's max health, has 50% of his armor/mr, and take 33% reduced ae damage.
   - Based on the bloblet's life on joining is the amount Zac will be at.(eg. if ones dead, another is at 50% and the other 2 are at 100%, Zac will revive at 30%).
   - Bloblet's are treated as minions in terms of abilities like consume and smite.
5. 3c [Aatrox's Blood Well](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aatrox/Ability_Details) passive.

   - The amount of health returned is equal to the amount in the blood well + (10.5 + 15.75*lvl).
   - Affected by passive of [Spirit Visage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Visage).
6. [Yorick's Omen of Death](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yorick/Ability_Details) ability. Caveats being:

   - Omen of Death has the lowest priority in terms of revival because it does not resurrect the champion, only revives them temporarily. This means that if an ally were to die while under the effects of  Zilean's  Chrono Shift or  Guardian Angel as well as  Omen of Death, the champion would be affected by the one that prevents death.
   - In Dominion, during the reincarnation of Omen of Death, Yorick or the champion brought back can not capture a point or stabilize a point to stop it from firing at an ally.
   - During the reincarnation of Omen of Death, you cannot use any summoner spells.

Other notes: Although not considered a revive ability, [Mordekaiser's Children of the Grave](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mordekaiser_the_Master_of_Metal/Ability_Details) ability has lowest priority.  In most cases, the debuff is cleared by the original death if the person is revived. When Aniva's ghost is revived by this ability, it may enter the egg state, but this will not affect the actual Aniva's ability cooldown.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Patch [**V1.0.0.113**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.113#General) revive effects trigger in this order:

> - [Tryndameres Undying Rage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tryndamere_the_Barbarian_King/Ability_Details#Undying_Rage)
> - [Zileans Chrono Shift](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zilean_the_Chronokeeper/Ability_Details#Chrono_Shift)
> - [Guardian Angel](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Angel#Notes) (GA)
> - [Anivias Rebirth](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Anivia_the_Cryophoenix/Ability_Details#Rebirth)

This means if you would die as a Tryndamere with Guardian Angel and your Ultimate is available, your ultimate would trigger first - goes on cooldown, gives you fury and GAs passive is still available. This means if you get the Chrono Shift Buff at the right moment (when Undying Rage ends) Tryndamere could technically drop to zero health 3 times before a kill is awarded.

Comment: If you want to be technical, Tryndamere isn't a revive ability, it is a immune to dying

Answer (score 0):

Tested this with a buddy a while ago as Anivia and Zillean:

The order of which i got revived:
Chronoshift -> Egg -> Guardian Angel

Still unsure whether or not Any of those can revive anivia while in egg form tho xD

Comment: Your answer raises an interesting question...(about the egg)