# What happens if Yorick uses his ultimate on Anivia's egg?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a duplicate of the egg or Anivia or nothing at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the precedence of Guardian Angel compared to other revive effects?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86401/what-is-the-precedence-of-guardian-angel-compared-to-other-revive-effects)

Comment: @Sconibulus This is not about precedence. I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: can he even use ultimate on anivias egg?

Comment: @Vogel612 Don't think so...

Comment: @3ventic It's partially about precedence, because it means that you'll have to be able to apply the Ultimate after she has morphed into an egg. This is an additional limitation you don't have with similar but negative effects (like Mordekaiser's Ultimate). You can't apply Yorick's Ultimate before, because it would keep her from becoming an egg at first.

Comment: This seems like something you could easily figure out yourself in a custom match...

Comment: @Mario Yorick's ult wouldn't prevent Anivia's egg, since Yorick's ult only happens when the champion *dies* (which Anivia's egg *prevents*).

Comment: Triggers later? Okay, thought Anivia's passive would be pretty much last, but makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried something that weird. :)

- If the egg isn't destroyed, nothing will happen. The check whether Anivia dies or is rescued by some ability happens before (when the egg is created). So her passive will begin it's cooldown no matter what and she'll be reborn.
- If the egg is destroyed, I assume one of the other effects might trigger again. This is something that might actually work even if you're unable to apply any of the other effects to the egg. Just imagine Guardian Angel ending its cooldown just before the egg is destroyed. That sounds like something really interesting (and complicated) to test though.
- Possibly important: I'm quite sure you'll get an Anivia Spirit if you're using Mordekaiser's Ultimate on her and the egg is killed. So I'd just say the same is true for Yorick's Ultimate (once the egg is destroyed).

Either way: You won't see a "Revenant Egg" or something like that. The champion is still Anivia, so you'd end up with an Anivia Revenant.

Comment: We should totally try this though to see what it results in

Comment: I play Anivia and have had this occur to me. No ghost unless the egg is destroyed. IF the egg does get shattered, then the ghost is Birdnivia, not Eggnivia. Source - I've played Anivia at least 1k games, had pretty much everything you can imagine happen to her at least once.