# How long can a champion be in stasis?

Tags: league-of-legends

While playing a game yesterday, the enemy Ziggs was wrecking us. So, we tried to focus our fire on him. Unfortunately, the enemy Zilean got his Ultimate on the Ziggs. While we were waiting for Ziggs to return, we were taking fire from the enemy team. When  he revived, he used Zhonya's Hourglass! It seemed like we were waiting forever for him to be target-able, and the rest of his team cleaned us up.

How long can any one champion remain untarget-able or in stasis in a row and under what circumstances can this occur?

Comment: Do you mean, how much time they are "dead" before they get back to life? it's something like 2 seconds and this isn't affected by any means

Comment: It depends on the champion as well.  I know some champions that can make themselves untargetable for a short period (Elise's repel, Vlad's pool, Fizz's trollpole, etc.), so that needs to be considered too.  Plus, there's some things that make enemies effectively untargetable for a wide range of abilities (Yasuo's Windwall, Braum's shield, anyone with invisibility, etc.).

Comment: A fun 'statis-troll' would be lissandra with zilean ult, her ult, GA and zhonyas. I cant think of anything else that would make it longer

Comment: @Michel No, I mean using Vlad pool followed by zhonya's, followed by guardian angel, followed by ... etc. How much total time?

Comment: This is the same as asking "What's the maxspeed that I can reach"... I don't think it's a good question because this doesn't help you in anyway and it's a too broad question

Comment: @BenCraig you forgot Kayle's ult.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Not exactly statis, but man, you just wouldn't die

Comment: @Michel why exactly should this question be closed? it's definitely not too broad.

Comment: I guess I meant not taking damage too, which would include Kayle's ultimate. Too late to change it now. FWIW, Kayle's maximum ultimate duration is 3 seconds

Comment: Trynd Ult is 5 seconds - it's a little different from some of the other things mentioned here, but if you're looking to troll by not being killable, I think it counts.

Comment: @Jutschge [Ordem of the buffs](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86401/what-is-the-precedence-of-guardian-angel-compared-to-other-revive-effects) is a good question, because it's **useful**! But this question is **NOT** there is no utility in strategy whatsoever in knowing "how long that guy can be in stasis", the usefulness is lost when you know the order of the spells. As I said, it's the **SAME** as asking "how fast can I get?" It's pointless, it changes over each patch, there isn't a "cap". You can add Yorick ult, Mordekaiser

Comment: ult, Anivia Ult The jump from Fizz and others stuffs that add 1 seg  to the calc. You have to build a SPECIFIC champion that will be **useless** in fight to get to this

Comment: @Michel Well I find the question quite interesting. It may not be the most useful one but it's perfectly on-topic and also answerable. ([Relevant](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one))

Comment: @Jutschge the close vote wasn't because of "I think this question is not good" as I said, this is **Too Broad**.

Comment: @Michel well I see 2 upvoted answers that aren't extremely long or different from eachother. **This question doesn't meet the criteria of any of the close reasons**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order they would go off:

Elise Repel - 2 Seconds

Zilean Ult - 2 Seconds

Guardian Angel - 4 Seconds

Zhonya's Hourglass - 2.5 Seconds

Elise Repel (Second time) - 2 Seconds

Total Time - 12.5 Seconds.

Elise repel is 14 second cooldown base. This means with 40% cdr, the cool down is 8.4 seconds. The combination of GA, Zilean ultimate, and Zhonyas gives you 8.5 seconds of stasis. This means you repel would be off cooldown by the time the rest of it is finished.

For stasis on other characters (vlad and fizz still take DoT damage in theirs):
Vlad pool is 2 seconds. Lissandra's self ult is 2.5. Fizz pole is 0.7 seconds. Aatrox passive is 3 seconds.

Comment: I thought elise took dot and leash damage while in repel? That's why you sometimes see her go up but never come down

Comment: Repel, along with Vlad pool, have animations going into and out of their stasis that may technically make the time where they can be damaged less than stated. I believe Elise can be damaged as she is coming down, and that time is not counted as part of the Repel time. Either way, Riot states 2 seconds, and that is their intent, regardless of bugs. The question also asked for stasis, which is that you cannot act, and you cannot be targeted. Invulnerability is a little bit different.

Answer (score 3):

If we're talking about real stasis (the one where you are **Completely Immortal**) the champion with the longest Total stasis duration would be **Aatrox**. Note that Fizz E and Vladimir E are still allowing ticking damage

This could be achieved through:

- Zilean Ultimate - 2s
- Zhonyas Hourglass - 2.5s
- Active Guardians Angel - 4s
- Fully Stacked Passive Revive - 3s

and it makes a total of **11.5 seconds of stasis**.

The only other champion that comes close to this is lissandra with **11 seconds** (just replace Aatrox passive with Lissandra Ultimate - 2.5s).

It's however more likely to encounter a Lissandra that fullfils these criteria since Zhonyas isn't really a commonly built item on Aatrox.

Comment: Don't forget Kayle's ult... not stasis but still unkillable.

Comment: And if the enemy team really wants to ruin your day they will smack a Yorick ult on Aatrox.

Comment: Zilean, Kayle, Aatrox and Yorick on the same team, possible. Gonna have to play with friends and try it.

Comment: It's always fun to see those videos where people take gimmicks like this and make a whole team around it. Giving someone like Draven or Jax extra lives, shields and untargetable protection.