# What's the longest a champion can continuously be invulnerable for?

Tags: league-of-legends

Not to be confused with [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181424/how-long-can-a-champion-be-in-stasis), I'm **not** asking about stasis and I'm interested in continuous application, not a simply chained one.

For how long can a champion be **continuously** immune to any damage directed at them (doesn't matter if they can or cannot be targeted)?

A valid sample combination:

- Kayle's ultimate
- Zhonya's Hourglass just before the former wears off

A sample invalid combination:

- Zhonya's Hourglass
- Kayle's ultimate

The latter is invalid because there is a small pocket of time during which the champion might theoretically take damage, since Kayle can't cast the ultimate on the champion under Zhonya's while it's active.

What's the longest such valid combination (in seconds, not by number of spells)?

Comment: I'm failing to see how your question differs from the one that you linked.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill There was a lengthy discussion on that point here in the comments before, but it seems it was removed by a moderator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be 5.5 seconds for every champion and 13.5 seconds for Poppy.

Since you won't allow a small time window it works as follows:

For every champion:
Kayle ultimate - 3 seconds
Stasis (Bard R, Lissandra R, Zhonya's Hourglass) - 2.5 Seconds

Now of course you'd have to time this absolutely perfectly and as you've mentioned slightly before kayle ultimate wears off.

Poppy can extend the invulnerability to 13 seconds with her ultimate but only from champions that aren't targeted by her ultimate.

Tryndamere can also add in his ultimate to a Zhonya's and Kayle ult. He doesn't really become immune to damage but he cannot die. He can extend the duration of his "unkillable" state to 10.5 seconds

Comment: and kalista ultimate

Comment: Kalista's ultimate can't be cast on stasis champs, and won't be instantaneous either, so that'd be under invalid. We had two bards, and I swear to God this fiddlesticks was invincible for an entire teamfight including his whole ult, the both had impeccable timing, but it's still invalid. Two bard's, Kayle, kalista, zhonya's, and champions with their own (tryndamere, poppy, Lissandra) can be invulnerable for longer than anyone would reasonably want or need to be, but there is a slight window.

Comment: Since Bard's ult does not target, wouldn't it be possible to time it such that it overlaps exactly with Zhonya's? Kayle Ult -> Zhonya's -> Bard Ult?

Comment: @JohnCleaver no this wouldn't work. It would leave open an extremely tiny gap in between since stasis prevents you from entering another stasis.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. Even if you got it frame perfect, another skill shot could land on the same frame.

Comment: The invulnerability can start with 4 seconds of Guardian Angel revive.

Comment: @Hackworth Again this would leave open a tiny window.

Comment: Then replace Kayle ult with GA procc, 1 extra second.

Comment: @Hackworth As I said. There's a tiny window between the GA revive and the stasis. It asks for a solution with absolutely no gap.

Comment: Then I don't understand the concept of tiny window. If you can perfectly time Kayle ult into Bard ult, why not GA into Bard ult?

Comment: @Hackworth because Kayle ult doesn't protect you from stasis but stasis prevents a Kayle ult.

Comment: You are talking about perfect timing, however. That would mean you can hit the Bard ult at the exact frame when GA animation ends. The only barrier to a continuous chain would be a cast time of a spell that can't start before the previous invulnerability has worn off.

Comment: @Hackworth The OP has described in his question why your scenario isn't valid in his eyes. If you have any further questions, please join us in [Summoners Rift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift) to avoid further flooding in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

In the normal game, the answer to your question is Poppy. But since Riot has now released URF or Ultra Rapid Fire, the answer to that question is Vladimir. He can pool about three times and then Zhonya's and then pool three more times. That is 6 seconds the first time then 2.5 and another 6 seconds for a whooping 14.5 seconds of invulnerability.

Comment: Vladimirs W does not make him invulnerable,just untargetable.

Comment: we could say the same about zhonias, the only thing that zhonias prevents is dot damage.  Vlad and fizz being untargeteable means they can't be hit with skillshots neither

Answer (score 0):

kayle ult -> lissandra self ult -> zhonyas -> kalista ult -> bard ult would be the longest combo, not sure on the maths, and there may be a few milliseconds here or there that prevent this being constant

Comment: The steps after Zhonya leave small windows of opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it would be something like:

-Poppy's Ultimate (8seconds)

-Kayle's Ultimate (3seconds)

-Kalista's Ultimate (4seconds)

I couldn't figure a way of adding Zhonya's/Bard's Ultimate in there without there being a small gap. So I think that is the longest I can think of.